# Building First App Tutorial Button not working

Tags: java, android, button, intellij-idea

So, I'm currently trying to make an android app with the tutorial on the android page, build your first app.(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html?hl=it)
I'm doing it on Intellji, so I found it a bit different.. So, I made it up to the third part, where I make the interface, but things got weird in the forth part, where I create another activity.

I created the displaymessageactivity.java file, and copied the code from the site. 
Then the problem I found was that because the file wasn't made automatically, or for some other reason, Intellij didn't know what to do with the R.id.action_settings and with the container. So, I looked over the code, and figured that for now, for the "STart Another Activity" section, I only needed the "onCreate" Method. So I greyed out theonOptionsItemSelected boolean for now.

When I ran this, however, The interface came out but the Send button didn't do anything when its suppose to show a new page with the message... So, I was wondering how to get this fixed.

These are my codes

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
}
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.myfirstapp.R;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setTextSize(40);
    textview.setText(message);

    setContentView(textview);
}
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() { }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_message, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created an `Intent` in `sendMessage`, however you forgot to start a activity with it. Just add

```
startActivity(intent);
```

at the end of the function and it should work (If your layout file is correct of course).

See [Start the Second Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#StartActivity)

Comment: Thank you. It worked.... I feel quite stupid for that.....
Do you know what the "onOptionsItemSelected" is for by any chance?
because I can't figure out what to do with the action_setting, which has a red line

Comment: @jerichoi224: It's for handling the clicks on the options, see [Creating an Options Menu -> Handling click events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#RespondingOptionsMenu)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have a step by step tutorial on Android development I think this site will be the best for you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

Don't fast forward on reading as well cause you might missed out some parts. :D

Also your Button won't work since you may have set the view on your MainActivity class, also initialized the button but you haven't set any listeners on it. So it just appears as a button but doesn't function at all. read my comments below:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

Button button; //<-- You initialize your button
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); //<-- this layout shoud contain a button
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID); //<-- locate your button based on the id from the main layout above

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //DO SOMETHING HERE let's say it's the method below:
            sendMessage(//but you need the parent view here or try using view or this but it will use this button as it's view as far as I know)
        }
    }); //<-- this whole part is the one that will handle the operation you will need once the button is clicked.

}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = String.valueOf(editText.getText());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
}
}
```

Comment: If the layout is done right, there is a `Button` element in the main layout that has a `onClick` attribute with the value `"sendMessage"`. That's discribed in the tutorial section [Respond to the Send Button](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#RespondToButton). Adding an unused field of type `Button` won't break the app. btw: Your code doesn't start a new activity.

Comment: Though the thing is we're not sure if the layout is done right. Also it was his code, I just added a few lines and some comments. :D

Comment: Thank you for the help, as well as the link for tutorial